# How can I decode Ed25519 addresses to the regular 56 letters format?

Tags: stellar-core, xdr, encoding

I've been trying to use the [stellar-archivist](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/tools/stellar-archivist) command 'dumpxdr' to unpack transactions files that are stored in the stellar core history

However the in the results asset codes and addresses appear in an unusual format:

```
"Asset": {
                                    "Type": 1,
                                    "AlphaNum4": {
                                        "AssetCode": [
                                            66,
                                            84,
                                            67,
                                            0
                                        ],
                                        "Issuer": {
                                            "Type": 0,
                                            "Ed25519": [
                                                63,
                                                240,
                                                248,
                                                202,
                                                234,
                                                182,
                                                83,
                                                235,
                                                9,
                                                242,
                                                59,
                                                84,
                                                254,
                                                175,
                                                46,
                                                84,
                                                240,
                                                194,
                                                151,
                                                210,
                                                16,
                                                45,
                                                49,
                                                56,
                                                1,
                                                35,
                                                9,
                                                153,
                                                40,
                                                229,
                                                92,
                                                245
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
```

I would like to see it as a regular stellar address (56 letters, starts with G)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which cryptographic algorithm is used to generate the secret and public keys?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/255/which-cryptographic-algorithm-is-used-to-generate-the-secret-and-public-keys)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Start with 32 bytes
- Add a byte of 0x30 as prefix 'G' (now you have 33 bytes)
- Calculate the checksum (two bytes)
- Add the checksum as suffix (now you have 35 bytes)
- Convert them to base32
- That's your public key

Apply the same but using 'S' (byte 0x90) as prefix for secret keys

Comment: Which type of checksum? Is it CRC32? If so, doesn't that provide four bytes?

Comment: Ah, I believe the checksum is CRC16-CCITT (based on looking at the Python code referenced below).

Comment: ChecksumXmodem from what I've read

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer using the [stellar python library](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base/tree/master/stellar_base)

```
from stellar_base import utils
x = bytearray(Ed25519 array here)  
account = utils.encode_check('account',x)
```

However I still have no idea what exactly is happening here, so I would appreciate any answer regardless :)